# Ruby Geocoder is throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I am working on RoR and using **Ruby Geocoder** for IP identification. The code snippet I  use giving below.

**Gemfile**

```
gem "geocoder"
```

Then for fetching country I am using

```
country = request.location.country
```

It was working perfectly before,but now it is throwing an error like  **undefined method country for nil class**.

I am not able to figure out the issue. Can any one help me to find out the solution or suggest any other gem on API for finding country based on IP Address

Thanks
Regards

Comment: You need to share more code. All we know what you've shared so far as that `request.location` returns `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay.Sorry to say that I am only using this much code for getting country. It was perfectly returning the country before. Now the doubt is why request.location is throwing nil error. Is any updation has been done recently?

Comment: To be clear, `request.location` isn't throwing any error. It is simply returning `nil`. There must be more code, however, as `request` is undefined as is.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, But when I use request.ip I am able to get the IP address. And the code I have using is directly from http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to have been an issue with Geocoder service. Even my application that runs on AWS was giving same problem for last 36'ish hours. Its all working well now. I didn't do anything, that makes me imply there was something wrong with Geocoder which they have apparently fixed now.

I wonder if this has happened in the past as it certainly worries me.

Comment: Thank you, For me also It happened from yesterday morning. I will check mine also now because I have hard-coded for running application smoothly.

Comment: This entirely depends on the service being used. If you're using the default (Google Maps), it's unlikely that the service has been down for this long, IMO.

Comment: @zeantsoi actually I use Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a local development environment, `request.location` will more than likely return `nil`. According to [the docs](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#request-geocoding-by-ip-address):

> Note that [request.location] will usually return nil in your test and development environments because things like "localhost" and "0.0.0.0" are not an Internet IP addresses.

Accordingly, the particular issues involved with `nil` exception should – for the most part – be limited to development environments. While developing locally, `nil` exceptions can handled using Ruby exception handling or the Rails [`try` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

```
request.location.try(:country)
```

**UPDATE**:

As @nonocut explains in his answer, this issue cited in the question may be due to some sort of problem with Google Maps. Nevertheless, it's important to be able to handle these outages via exception handling – it's good for local development, and it makes for pragmatic deployment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.It is throwing error in my staging environment.

Comment: Some staging environments are local – is yours?

Comment: No,We are Using aws ec2 with specific DNS.